# C++ vector iterator + offset out of range

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, range, offset

I have c++ code that compiles on Xcode, but when I try to compile it on Visual Studio 2015 I get an error that iterator offset is out of range. Can someone try to help to figure this out:

```
typename std::vector< HNode<T>* >::iterator ti;

while(temp.size() > 1) {
    std::sort(temp.rbegin(), temp.rend(), HNodePointerCountComparator<T>());

    ti = temp.end();
    ti -= 1;

    temp.push_back(new HNode<T>());
    temp.back()->setCount(temp.back()->getCount() + (*ti)->getCount());
    temp.back()->setLeft(*ti);

    temp.erase(ti);

    ti -= 1; //Debug assertion failed: iterator + offset out of range

    temp.back()->setCount(temp.back()->getCount() + (*ti)->getCount());
    temp.back()->setRight(*ti);

    temp.erase(ti); 
}
```

Comment: *I have c++ code that compiles* -- It is not compilation that is the issue.  It is when your program runs that is the issue.  Having said this, what exactly on a high-level are you trying to accomplish with this code?  It isn't recommended to erase from a `vector` while iterating over the same `vector`.

Comment: Also,the program has a bug that was hidden from you, even if you say it runs in XCode.  Be happy that Visual Studio detected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`erase` invalidates `ti`, so when you try to modify it afterwords the debug build in VS will flag it.

What you want to do is

```
ti = temp.erase(ti);
```

which will have `ti` refer to the first element after the one you erased.  In practice, this means that `ti` won't change (as that first element will be moved down replacing the one that was erased), but the iterator tracking in debug builds with Visual Studio will be happy with it.

Comment: Also note that `push_back` may also invalidate `ti` if it causes a reallocation in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer provided, this also can invalidate an iterator:

```
   ti = temp.end();
   ti -= 1;
   temp.push_back(new HNode<T>());
```

Calling `push_back()` will result in iterator invalidation.  So your `ti` iterator may not be valid after the call to `push_back`.

Instead of us giving reasons why you're having these issues, you should state exactly what your goal is in that `while` loop you've written.  I am sure you would get answers that will not only state what you're doing wrong, but also how to write the erasure code correctly.

The best way to not have these issues is to not write a loop that erases items from a `std::vector` while looping over the vector, and at the same time store iterators within the vector.  The way to accomplish this is to use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)  instead of trying to manage iterators and `while` loops.